# Compare two time values using jQuery's validate

Tags: php, jquery, validation, comparison

I have two selects, one that is a time from and the other is a time to.  These values are split by fifteen minute integrals. I take those values and convert them using PHP's strtotime. I would like to compare these values to make sure that the time to is not lower than the time from or that the time from is not higher than the time to using jQuery's validate.

Thanks.
Here is my PHP:

```
$start = strtotime('12:00 AM');
$end = strtotime('12:00 PM');

echo '<select name="TimeFrom" id="TimeFrom"  class="timeSelectFrom">';
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 900)
{
    echo '<option>' . date('g:i A', $i) . '</option>';
}
echo '<option>Closed</option>';

$start = strtotime('12:00 AM');
$end = strtotime('12:00 PM');
echo '<select name="TimeTo" id="TimeTo" class="timeSelectTo">';
for ($i = $start; $i <= $end; $i += 900)
{
    echo '<option>' . date('g:i A', $i) . '</option>';
}
echo '<option>Closed</option>';
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: pls clarify "time to is not higher than the time to using jQuery's validate"

Comment: Oops, I meant time from is not higher than the time to. IE, From: 1PM To: 10AM would generate an error.

Comment: aren't "time to is not lower than the time from" and "time from is not higher than the time to" the same thing? why specify it twice?

Comment: Yes, they are. I guess I did it for clarification? Heh.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily translate the values from the form elements into a basic time-stamp using a simplistic formula like (seconds+60*minutes) and then compare them as required.